# Google maps mapType coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, tile

I've got a little problem here.

### What i want to do.

On my server i have a table with markers that have lat, lng, [tile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx) fields in it.
There are a lot of markers in table so i request them by tiles that are visible to the user.
To make it working as it should is my final goal.

### Problem

I wanted to solve this by creating my own [mapType](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=#CustomMapTypes) and define method `getTile()` that will be responsible for requesting appropriate tiles from server using `x/y/z` notation where x,y are the coordinates of tile and z is the zoom level. More about this you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=en#TileCoordinates). There is my code(i'm using [jquery-ui-map plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) here):

```
function ServerFetchMapType() {

      this.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256,256);
      this.maxZoom = 15;
      this.name = "Server Tile #s";
      this.alt  = "Server Data Tile Map Type";

      this.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument){

        //Data for request
        var x = coord.x;
        var y = coord.y;
        var z = zoom;

        //Here i will make an ajax request for markers in this tile

        //Visualization
        var div = ownerDocument.createElement('DIV');
        div.innerHTML = 'X:' + coord.x + ' Y:' +  coord.y + ' Z:' +  zoom;
        div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
        div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
        div.style.fontSize = '10';
        div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
        div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
        div.style.borderColor = '#AAAAAA';
        return div;

      };

    }

    var test = new ServerFetchMapType();

    $('#map_canvas').gmap();
    $('#map_canvas').gmap('get', 'map').overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, test);
```

Everything worked but then i found one drawback, i will illustrate it:

[image]

As you can see only 4 tiles in the center of the picture have the [right](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=en#TileCoordinates) `x/y/z` notation and therefore all the tiles that are descendants of this tiles. But i won't be able to use other tiles to fetch data from server.

### Question

So what can i do to change coordinates of other tiles where the map is just repeating to have the same coordinates as main tiles? Or you can offer other way to solve this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very good man helped me to solve this problem this way:

```
     function ServerFetchMapType() {

      this.tileSize = new google.maps.Size(256,256);
      this.maxZoom = 15;
      this.name = "Server Tile #s";
      this.alt  = "Server Data Tile Map Type";

      this.getTile = function(coord, zoom, ownerDocument){

        var dim = Math.pow(2, zoom);

        //Data for request
        var x = Math.abs( coord.x ) % dim;
        var y = Math.abs( coord.y ) % dim;
        var z = zoom;



        //Visualization D
        var div = ownerDocument.createElement('DIV');        
        div.innerHTML = 'X:' + Math.abs( coord.x ) % dim  + ' Y:' +  Math.abs( coord.y ) % dim + ' Z:' +  zoom;

        div.style.width = this.tileSize.width + 'px';
        div.style.height = this.tileSize.height + 'px';
        div.style.fontSize = '10';
        div.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
        div.style.borderWidth = '1px';
        div.style.borderColor = '#AAAAA9';
        return div;

      };

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

All tiles in your screen shot have correct numbers, not just the central 4.

You should not have the 'tile' field in your markers table, only lat and lon. On your server side script you'd calculate the corners of the tile in question and select the markers that are within the range, such as:

```
Select * from markersTable 
where lat >= tile_SW_Lat and lat <= tile_NE_Lat 
and lon >= tile_SW_lon and lon <= tile_NE_lon
```

In all cases, you know that tile(x,y) values are 0 or positive integers. The API takes care of the wrapping for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help man. But i think that with tile id it will be slightly faster.

Comment: I doubt it, because with the 'tile id' field you have to repeat entries **for each marker for each zoom level**. Your table gets a lot bigger like that. (Sounds like Microsoft kind of "efficiency") :-)

Comment: Well, with tiles id you can check whether you already loaded markers from tile or not. And there is only one comparison when selecting from the table instead of two. And with one more int(15) column your table won't be much bigger.

Comment: Well, your app your choice, but it seems totally inefficient to me to have 15 entries for each marker when you could have just 1. I always try to have my databases normalized to 3NF: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by entry? Maybe you got me wrong.For example, using this technic of numerating the tiles http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx with quadkeys you will need only one request like this http://test.local/getMarkersByTileId/0001 all markers with tile ids like 0001% will be selected. One entry.

Comment: By 'entry' I mean 'record' (or row). Each marker appears again on each zoom level, but under a different tile number, therefore with your approach, you need to repeat a record for each marker for each zoom level. With 15 zoom levels your table gets 15 times bigger than it needs to be, (15 times the number of records).

Comment: You got me wrong. in my table each marker has only one tile id that corresponds to the tile on the max zoom level. And when tile on the higher level is requested: for example, max level 3 and tile id requested is 10, i will use select ... LIKE 10% . Like so.

Comment: A 'like' clause will never be faster than a 'where' clause with the proper indexes. But good luck anyway. :-)

Comment: Yes, you are right. But you can get rid of LIKE by using one tricky method with converting to another numbering system. So it's a matter of choice.